# why this simple ave function is not working

Tags: r

I am using following code and data:

```
> d <- data.frame(year = rep(2000:2002, each = 3), count = round(runif(9, 0, 20)))
> d
  year count
1 2000     1
2 2000     4
3 2000     4
4 2001    14
5 2001     8
6 2001    15
7 2002    10
8 2002    14
9 2002    20
> 
> with(d, ave(count, year, sum))
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

I tried:

```
> with(d, ave(count, list(year), sum))
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
> with(d, ave(count, list('year'), sum))
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
> 
> with(d, ave(count, 'year', sum))
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors

> with(d, ave('count', 'year', sum))
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
> ave(d$count, d$year, sum)
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors

> ave(d$count, factor(d$year), sum)
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors

> ave(d$count, unique(d$year), sum)
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors

> ave(d$count, factor(unique(d$year)), sum)
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
> ave(d$count, as.factor(unique(d$year)), sum)
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

Following works:

```
> unique(d$count)
[1]  1  4 14  8 15 10 20
> unique(d$year)
[1] 2000 2001 2002
```

tapply, aggregate and by work:

```
> with(d, tapply(count, year, mean))
    2000     2001     2002 
 3.00000 12.33333 14.66667 

> with(d, aggregate(count, list(year), mean))
  Group.1        x
1    2000  3.00000
2    2001 12.33333
3    2002 14.66667

> with(d, by(count, year, mean))
year: 2000
[1] 3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
year: 2001
[1] 12.33333
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
year: 2002
[1] 14.66667
```

Why there is error 'unique() applies only to vectors' and how can I use ave function here?

Comment: This is kind of subtle, but try your first attempt again but with an explicit FUN = sum

Comment: with(d, ave(count, list(year), FUN=sum))  works. Thanks. Why does it not assume it to be a function while 'tapply', 'aggregate' and 'by' do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a little subtle and I think the best documentation of this is actually in the R language definition on [argument matching](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching):

> The first thing that occurs in a function evaluation is the matching
> of formal to the actual or supplied arguments. This is done by a
> three-pass process:
>
> 1. Exact matching on tags. For each named supplied argument the list of
>    formal arguments is searched for an item whose name matches exactly.
>    It is an error to have the same formal argument match several actuals
>    or vice versa.
> 2. Partial matching on tags. Each remaining named supplied
>    argument is compared to the remaining formal arguments using partial
>    matching. If the name of the supplied argument matches exactly with
>    the first part of a formal argument then the two arguments are
>    considered to be matched. It is an error to have multiple partial
>    matches. Notice that if f <- function(fumble, fooey) fbody, then f(f =
>    1, fo = 2) is illegal, even though the 2nd actual argument only
>    matches fooey. f(f = 1, fooey = 2) is legal though since the second
>    argument matches exactly and is removed from consideration for partial
>    matching. If the formal arguments contain ‘...’ then partial matching
>    is only applied to arguments that precede it.
> 3. Positional matching. Any
>    unmatched formal arguments are bound to unnamed supplied arguments, in
>    order. If there is a ‘...’ argument, it will take up the remaining
>    arguments, tagged or not.

So this is a result of the special nature of the `…` argument. It is, in a sense, "greedy", unless you are more explicit and used named arguments. The reason this doesn't pop up elsewhere is because `…` is usually the last (or nearly last) argument, so you don't often end up with this sort of confusing behavior when using positional matching.